# Search Access Database with C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple code that can search fields in an access database.
Now I need to change it to this parameters:

1. Search a query in all fields in one textbox something like:

   `"select * from Sheet where * like@*"`
2. Show the results in labels instead GridView.

I make an oleDbCommand and connect it to an oleDbConnection and my oleDbConnection is:

**Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Database.accdb**

I use of Visual C# 2010 and an .accdb Access database.
This is my code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DataSet DSOne = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter adpSearch = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adpSearch.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    adpSearch.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;
    adpSearch.SelectCommand.CommandText = " select * from Sheet where OfficeNumber  like@OfficeNumber ";
    adpSearch.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeNumber", textBox1.Text + "%");
    adpSearch.Fill(DSOne, "toop");
    dataGridView.DataSource = DSOne;
    dataGridView.DataMember = "toop";
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Search a query in all fields in one textbox something like:

    "select * from Sheet where * like@*"

    Show the results in labels instead GridView.

Comment: Excuse me but this is two separate question in a topic because I worry about Junk!

Answer (score 0):

```
adpSearch.SelectCommand.CommandText = " select * from Sheet where OfficeNumber  like %@OfficeNumber%";
adpSearch.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeNumber", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: orry but I gave this erroe: Syntax error in query expression 'OfficeNumber  like %@OfficeNumber%'.

Comment: Can I use If command in adpSearch.SelectCommand.CommandText ?

Comment: " select * from Sheet where OfficeNumber  like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' " This working but just search in OfficeNumber field. I need it search in all fields!?